# Difference between “jmdm. helfen” and “behilflich sein”

Tags: difference, usage

Are these two expressions equal synonyms? Is there any difference in the usage/meaning? 
In the following example they are interchangeable:

> Könnt ihr mir bitte *behilflich sein*?
>
> Könnt ihr mir bitte *helfen*?

It seems to me that there is no difference but I’m not sure if it works like this also in different sentence structures and contexts.

I’ve already read [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/usage-of-verhelfen-helfen-and-behelfen/8190#8190) and [this other](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/hilfsbereit-vs-hilfreich) topics that cover *hilfreich, hilfsbereit, behelfen, verhelfen.* There are so many words derived from *helfen* that I’m no more sure about anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are right but

> behilflich

sounds more like assisting someone and a little bit old fashioned while

> helfen

is more like really helping someone.

For example:

> Könntest du mir beim Deutsch lernen behilflich sein?

could be understood like “Could you give me some advice?” while

> Könntest du mir beim Deutsch lernen helfen?

is more like “could you sit down with me and learn vocabulary?”

> helfen

ist stronger and implies more work than

> behilflich sein

Comment: That's useful. I understand better the difference now (there are equivalent expressions in my language)...but reading @Burki comment I was thinking about this: maybe in a general context they implies the same amount of work, while in a specific one there is the difference you are talking about. Not sure, maybe I can try write an answer myself in order to explain this better

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps to answer your question from the title:

> jmd. helfen | behilflich sein

Translated this means:

> to help someone | to offer (ones/your) help